# Pagination using a c# list

Tags: c#, linq

At the min, I have a for loop which is to go round a set of List items one at a time. But the issue I am having the bin prompt is showing right away for each item I tried using has been scanned boolean to signify the user has scanned but of course, i still want the action the dialogue to be shown the first time but then not until the user has scanned something show it again might just be my logic messed up.

It's a recursive loop I was wanting but with a pagination element to it so it would be doing the action one record at a time.

```
int i = 0;
do
    {

        binInfo = await restServices.GetWarehouseBinsInformaiton(globalBomSource[i].StockCode, SouceWarehouseName);                

       var binPrompt = await DisplayAlert("System", $"Bin Location {binInfo.BinName} for Item { globalBomSource[i].Description} Qty Required { globalBomSource[i].Quantity}", "Scan", "Cancel");

            if (binPrompt == true)
            {
                var scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage();
                scanPage.ToggleTorch();
                scanPage.IsScanning = true;


                await Navigation.PushAsync(scanPage);
                var resultcode = txtCode.Text;


                scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) =>
                {
                    string barcode = result.Text;


                    // Stop scanning
                    scanPage.IsScanning = false;
                    // Pop the page and show the result
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                        {

                            var item = await restServices.Get_BomSingleTransaciton(resultcode, settingsFuel.DeviceID.ToString(), globalBomSource[i].BarCode, BomAmountRequired);
                            RefCode = result.Text;
                            txtbarcode.Text = result.Text;
                            await Navigation.PopAsync();
                            bomInfo = await restServices.GetBomTransactions(resultcode, settingsFuel.DeviceID.ToString(), BomAmountRequired);
                            int coucountbomnt = bomInfo.Count();

                            if (item != null)
                            {

                                var resultQty = await Plugin.DialogKit.CrossDiaglogKit.Current.GetInputTextAsync("System", $"Bin Location {binInfo.BinName} for Item { globalBomSource[i].Description} Qty Required { globalBomSource[i].Quantity}", null, Keyboard.Numeric);


                                if (resultQty != null)
                                {
                                    Int32.TryParse(resultQty, out int resultValue);


                                    await SaveBomTransFer(_boms[i].BarCode, resultValue);
                                    i++;
                                    hasbeenScanned = true;

                                }

                            }

                        });

                };
            }

        } while (i < globalBomSource.Count);
```

[video]

```
 https://streamable.com/bir98
```

[/video]

Answer (score 1):

> Its like i need to be able to access it like the old index arrays to be able to loop through it invidually i think and then move next.

Not sure if this is a part of your question, but you can access specific elements of a List just like an array.

```
List<int> list = new List<int> () { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
Console.Write (list[3]); // Writes 40
```

---

In regards to the rest of your question, it sounds like you're trying to iteratively access each element in your list to do something with them without necessarily being bound to a `foreach` loop.

You have a couple of options, simplest of which being to access each element with an `int` indexer as you alluded to before. You can also get the list's `Enumerator` and move though it manually if you prefer that way.

```
var enumerator = list.GetEnumerator ();

// Must be called after an enumerator is created to get a valid Current value.
enumerator.MoveNext ();

// enumerator.Current will return the first element of the list until MoveNext is called again.
var current = enumerator.Current;
```

For further reading you can look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator?view=netframework-4.8).